# Knockout is generating two bindings for single foreach

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm facing headache issue that led me to spend two days looking for a solution for it. I hope anyone would help me with it. I'm using knockout to generate bindings with json data for HTML markups. However, I'm not able to change the css of the element because I realized the element is generated twice and assigned the same id. Here's snippet of my code

```
<div id = 'divBinder' data-bind="foreach: Results" >        
            <div id='rowStyle' class='eligibilitydivContentTableRow'  >
            <div class='eligibilitydivContentLeftCell' style="float:left;"  data-bind=" text: RequirementDescription"></div>
            <div class='eligibilitydivContentMiddleCell' style="float:left;">
            <span class='spanClass'></span>
            <input class='inputRadio' type='radio'  value:'true' data-bind="attr: { checked: IsChecked,'name': $index() }" />
            <span class='spanClass'></span>
            </div>
            <div class='eligibilitydivContentRightCell' style="float:left;"><span class='spanClass'></span>
            <input class='inputRadio2' type='radio' value:'false'  data-bind="attr: { checked: IsChecked, 'name': $index(), onclick:'testFunction.apply(this);return true;'}"     />
                <span class='spanClass'></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div data-bind=" attr: {'id': getSuffixRowID($index())}" style="display:none;"  >
            <div style="float:left;">
                <textarea > </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='dateField' onfocus='showDate()' /></div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

Here are the javascript function I'm using to generate ids

```
function getSuffixRowID(suffix) {
       // alert(suffix);
        return 'hiddenRows' + suffix;
    }
```

Here's my binding

```
  viewModel = [];
     viewModel.Results = ko.mapping.fromJS(globalizedData.Results);


     ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("parentDivElement"));
     ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("parentDivElement"));
```

Note that the RequirementDescription is binded correctly. The only problem is setting the css through testFunction being called when button is checked

```
function testFunction() {
        //    jQuery('#' + getSuffixRowID(this.attributes[6].nodeValue)).hide();
        var nodeId = this.attributes['name'].nodeValue;
        var stringValue = this.value;
        switch (stringValue) {
            case ('true'):
                viewModel.Results()[nodeId].IsCompleted(true);
                viewModel.Results()[nodeId].IsChecked(true);
               break;
            case ('false'):

               viewModel.Results()[nodeId].IsCompleted(false);
                viewModel.Results()[nodeId].IsChecked(false);
                var idName = getSuffixRowID(nodeId);
                 $('#' + idName).css('display', 'block !important;');
                break;
        }
    }
```

The id for checkbox elements are assigned via $index variable inside foreach. I realized the duplicate generation through taking a look at the generate html page. It has two duplicate foreach markups. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way you should code with KnockoutJS :

```
onclick:'testFunction.apply(this);return true;'}
```

The Result object should have two properties (one for each checkbox).
So assuming your Result object looks like :

```
var Result = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.checkbox1 = ko.observable();
    self.checkbox2 = ko.observable();
};
```

The binding the checkbox will be :

```
onclick: $parent:testFunction, value : checkbox2
```

You can add the id binding if you want.

And the TestFunction :

```
function testFunction(result/* the result item */) {
   if(result.checkbox2()) {

   }
   [...]
};
```

With Knockout you souldn't modify the view directly. You have to leverage the viewModel and knockout will modify the view for you.

Please take a look at the [visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) too.

I hope it helps.